# Custom Filter for Kendo UI multiselect asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I have a multiselect created with the below code

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => model.data)
        .Name("SampleData")
        .AutoClose(false)
        .MaxSelectedItems(10)
        .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("GetData", "SampleData");
                });
            })
        )
```

In Controller I'm returning a list with around 1000 items
The datasource is something like below having
`List<string> listitem=new List<string>(){"value item 1 here", "this item is 2", "some other value here"......}`

Is there any way such that when i enter something in the kendo multiselect it filter the values based on the start of the words in the sentences of that string list?
for eg:
if i enter "ite" it should show all the sentences of that string list which has words starting with "ite".

Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

I have seen some filters like "startswith" which only checks the start of the sentences and "contains" which checks even the substring of the words. But what I'm trying to get is some filtering which check the start of all the words in the sentence and then filter it based on the match.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add:

```
.Filter("startswith")
```

Other values you can use are "contains" and "endswith".

See the api reference for MVC here: https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/kendo.mvc.ui.fluent/multiselectbuilder

The jquery version is here where you can open the example in a Dojo to see how it should work: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect/configuration/filter